If both goods are considered economic goods in the economy, then how can their demand be negatively sloped when in a state of satiation or bliss?
if both goods are economic bad, then we can say that they have a negatively sloped demand curve. But how can we say the same for economic goods in a state of satiation or bliss?

Can you please clarify the source of this claim or provide a lot more context?
